# Insert a complex multidimensional array into SQL, not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I've been searching for days, now i got to ask here ...
I have 1 array which i'd like to insert into sql .. however the structure of the array makes it difficult.

```php
$the_array = [
    [
        "3_Bachelor",
        [
            3 => "English",
            4 => "German"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "3_Master",
        [
            1 => "Marketing",
            2 => "Accountancy"
        ]
    ]
];
```

Here is the first draw, not working :

```
$id = "3";

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id,i d_training_key ,training_lectures)
VALUES (:id, :id_training_key, :training_lectures)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($the_array as $lec => $l) {
  foreach ($l as $a) {
    $stmt->execute($l[0], $id, $a);
  }
}
```

The difficult part lays in the array, in the array, in array ... You see what i mean ?

The DB looks like and "English" and "German" should be in one single line with 'id' and 'id_training_key' repeated on each line:
id | id_training_key | training_lectures

Do you guys have any idea or hint ?
If you thing that the array should be restructured, what's your opinion ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: To help clarify, which three values from your array do you want to populate your query with? Right now you're trying to insert an array for the parameter `training_lectures` - do you want English and German concatenated as a string, a separate line inserted per, or...?

Comment: @TCooper thx for comment and the edit ;) The following answers should clarify all your questions :
The three values got to be inserted in the db, in three different fields / columns.
Ideally, `training_lectures` should be inserted as separate lines. But if a string with a delimiter is the only solution, then I'd be okay with it.
Do you think that the current structure of the array is appropriate for such query ?

Comment: Could you please show a SQL example of what the inserts should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you are using named parameters but only passing in a positional array.

When executing statements in a loop, it can often be simpler to bind parameters pre-emptively and call `execute()` without any arguments. Try something like this

```php
$id_training_key = 3;
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, id_training_key, training_lectures)
    VALUES (:id, :id_training_key, :training_lectures)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->bindParam(":id_training_key", $id_trainging_key);
$stmt->bindParam(":training_lectures", $lang);

foreach ($the_array as [ $id, $langs ]) {
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

This will perform inserts with like

```sql
INSERT INTO users (id, id_training_key, training_lectures)
VALUES ('3_Bachelor', 3, 'English');

INSERT INTO users (id, id_training_key, training_lectures)
VALUES ('3_Bachelor', 3, 'German');

-- etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close to achieving what you want already.

```
$id = "3";

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id,id_training_key,training_lectures)
VALUES (:id,:id_training_key,:training_lectures)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($the_array as $lec => $l) {
  foreach ($l as $a) {
    foreach($a as $training_lecture){
        $stmt->execute([':id' => $l[0], ':id_training_key' => $id, ':training_lectures' => $training_lecture);
    }
  }
}
```

This will populate the query as `INSERT INTO users (id,id_training_key,training_lectures) VALUES ('3_Master','3','English')` for the first iteration. You can always test what you're queries will look like by replacing the execute statement with [manual value bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) (See example 1) and then echoing the statement after.